# Search for the value of a field in an XML file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing

I am trying to find the value of a field in an XML file using the following code

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET    

filename = ('TEST.xml')
root = ET.parse(filename)
root1 = root.getroot()
field = root1.findall('.//ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME').text
```

This returns the following error

```
field = root1.findall('.//ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME').text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The field ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME only appears once in the xml file

```
<Descriptive>
    <ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME>TEST_TEST</ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME>
    <CNTRY>US</CNTRY>
    <COUNTRY_CODE>US</COUNTRY_CODE>
</Descriptive>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.findall` returns a list, even if it is only one item, so use any of the following:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<Descriptive>
    <ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME>TEST_TEST</ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME>
    <CNTRY>US</CNTRY>
    <COUNTRY_CODE>US</COUNTRY_CODE>
  </Descriptive>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

# dereference list, fails if zero found, won't print more than one
field = root.findall('.//ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME')[0].text
print(field)

# iterate list, prints all found
for field in root.findall('.//ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME'):
    print(field.text)

# prints one, fails if not found
field = root.find('.//ALTERNATE_COMPANY_NAME').text
print(field)
```

Output:

```
TEST_TEST
TEST_TEST
TEST_TEST
```

Comment: I ran in you suggest code but it returned this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @SeánDempsey You didn't run my *exact* code, because it works.  `None` is returned if the code didn't find anything, then `.text` can't work on `None` just like it can't work on `list`.

Comment: okay so when running your exact code i see:

 File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

this is as the location of my file is derived from a directory so what I do in code is grab the xml file from this directory and then use it:

filename = get_latest_file_in_folder(download_dir)

root = ET.fromstring(filename)

Comment: @SeánDempsey The error message means you have invalid XML. `filename` is not XML. Use `parse` if you have a file name, and `fromstring` if you have XML in a string.